# Laravel Has One Through

Tags: laravel, eloquent

On laravel.com there is an example for Has One Through Relationships which is nearly exactly what I need.

https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#has-one-through

```
mechanics
    id - integer
    name - string

cars
    id - integer
    model - string
    mechanic_id - integer

owners
    id - integer
    name - string
    car_id - integer
```

My Database structure is exactly the same. But: In this example I think every car has exactly one owner. My problem is, that my owner has a lot of cars, so there is one small difference in the database:

```
mechanics
    id - integer
    name - string

cars
    id - integer
    model - string
    mechanic_id - integer
    owner_id - integer

owners
    id - integer
    name - string
```

And so, the code example is not working:

```
class Mechanic extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the car's owner.
     */
    public function carOwner()
    {
        return $this->hasOneThrough(Owner::class, Car::class);
    }
}
```

Do you have an idea, how to change the code to receive:

```
//The mechanic
echo $mechanic->name;

//The cars the mechanic is working on
foreach ($mechanic->cars as car) {
    echo $car->model;

    //The owner of the car (Maybe like this???)
    echo $car->model->owner->name;
}
```

Comment: if you have many cars for one owner, then probably you should use hasMany relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want the hasOneThrough relationship unless you're interested in a single car and not every car the mechanic is associated with.

```
//The mechanic Model
dump($mechanic);

//The mechanic's name attribute
dump($mechanic->name);

//The Collection of cars associated with the mechanic
dump($mechanic->cars);

// echoing the model attribute of the cars associated with the mechanic
foreach ($mechanic->cars as $car) {
    echo $car->model;
}

// The owner of ONLY the first car associated with the mechanic
dump($car->carOwner);

// echoing the model attribute of the cars associated with the mechanic and the car owner's name;
foreach ($mechanic->cars as $car) {
    echo $car->model;
    echo $car->owner->name;
}
```

```
// Eager loading both cars and associated owners from the Mechanic model:
Mechanic::with('cars.owner')->...
// or
$mechanic->load('cars.owner');
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your input. I totally misunderstood eager loading till now. Holy shit, that makes it so much easier! THX!